# Built arguments not getting properly passed

Tags: expl3

I've got some rather complicated arguments that I must build gradually and then pass to another macro.  The MWE is greatly simplified.

Here's my attempt using `expl3`.  The problem is that no matter how I try `\exp_args:....` (whether `NnV`, `Nno`, `Nnx`) the expansion is not happening as I expect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_aepoly_arguments_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\macroA{ mmmm }
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_aepoly_arguments_tl
      {
        {\fp_eval:n { #1*#3 }}
        {\fp_eval:n { #1*#4 + #2*#3 }}
        {\fp_eval:n { #2*#4}}
      }
    \iow_term:x {===> \l_aepoly_arguments_tl }
    \exp_args:NnV \_aepoly_parse:nnnn {SIMPLIFIED} \l_aepoly_arguments_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\macroB{ mmmm }
  {
    \_aepoly_parse:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \_aepoly_parse:nnnn #1#2#3#4 {
  %% something elaborate, but below will suffic for MWE
  \iow_term:n {===>(#1)[#2][#3][#4]}
  \fbox{#1} $\rightarrow #2x^2 + #3x + #4$
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\macroB{Poly}{3}{4}{5}

\macroA{2}{3}{5}{2}
{NOT}{THIS}

\end{document}
```

If I were to have written this without `expl3` I would have done something along the following lines which work as I expect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\aetypeout#1{\typeout{===>#1}}

\newcommand\macroA[4]{%%
  \def\ae@tmp@A{%%
      {\number\numexpr #1*#3\relax}%%
      {\number\numexpr #1*#4 + #2*#3\relax}%%
      {\number\numexpr #2*#4\relax}}%%
  \expandafter\aetypeout\expandafter{\l_aepoly_arguments_tl}%%
  \def\ae@tmp@B{{SIMPLIFIED}}%%
  \expandafter\ae@parse\expandafter\ae@tmp@B\ae@tmp@A
}

\newcommand\macroB[4]{\ae@parse{#1}{#2}{#3}{4}}

\def\ae@parse#1#2#3#4{%%
  \typeout {===>(#1)[#2][#3][#4]}%%
  \fbox{#1} $\rightarrow #2x^2 + #3x + #4$%%
}  

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\macroB{Poly}{3}{4}{5}

\macroA{2}{3}{5}{2}
{NOT}{THIS}

\end{document}
```

The advantage of the `expl3` is its ability to handle better arithmetic
(among other things).  I know I could have saved each part of the argument to a token list and then create a variant of `\_aepoly_parse:nnnn` such as `\_aepoly_parse:nVVV`.  But currently that would overly complicate things for the document I'm actually working on.

Comment: `\exp_args:NnV` adds braces around the value of the token list variable.

Comment: `\exp_last_unbraced:NV` might help (you have to change the order of the arguments in `\_aepoly_parse:nnnn`)

Comment: If `\xyz_funct:n` is the main macro, `\xyz_funct:V` is just calling the function as if its argument were the value of the variable.

Comment: @egreg `\exp_last_unbraced:Nno` works.  It also seems to work find without changing any order in the arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do

```
\cs_new:Npn \xyz_func:n #1
 {
  code with #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xyz_func:n { V }
```

then calling

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_xyz_var_tl { aaa }
\xyz_func:V \l_xyz_var_tl
```

is equivalent to calling

```
\xyz_func:n { aaa }
```

You have to do two steps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_aepoly_arguments_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\macroA{ mmmm }
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_aepoly_arguments_tl
   {
    {\fp_eval:n { #1*#3 }}
    {\fp_eval:n { #1*#4 + #2*#3 }}
    {\fp_eval:n { #2*#4}}
   }
  \iow_term:x {===> \l_aepoly_arguments_tl }
  \__aepoly_parse_aux:nV {SIMPLIFIED} \l_aepoly_arguments_tl
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\macroB{ mmmm }
 {
  \__aepoly_parse:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__aepoly_parse_aux:nn #1 #2
 {
  \__aepoly_parse:nnnn { #1 } #2
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__aepoly_parse_aux:nn { nV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aepoly_parse:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  %% something elaborate, but below will suffic for MWE
  \iow_term:n {===>(#1)[#2][#3][#4]}
  \fbox{#1} $\rightarrow #2x^2 + #3x + #4$
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\macroB{Poly}{3}{4}{5}

\macroA{2}{3}{5}{2}

\end{document}
```

So the auxiliary macro just calls the main one stripping off the braces.

[image]

Note that the convention for private functions is to have *two* underscores at the beginning. Also, the function `\__aepoly_parse:nnnn` should be protected.

You might use `\exp_last_unbraced:NV`, but when there are other methods, they are preferable.

Of course, you might simply do

```
\NewDocumentCommand\macroA{ mmmm }
 {
  \__aepoly_parse:nxxx
    {SIMPLIFIED}
    {\fp_eval:n { #1*#3 }}
    {\fp_eval:n { #1*#4 + #2*#3 }}
    {\fp_eval:n { #2*#4}}
  }
```

(generating the variant) if you don't need the diagnostic.

Comment: I hadn't thought of creating an auxiliary function to do the job.  Very nice way of avoiding `\exp_args:....`

Comment: Why the recommendation to *protect* `\__aepoly_parse:nnnn`?  I understand the situation from earlier today, but I'm not sure why that would apply in this situation.